# WebResponse response =response .GetResponse() giving Bad Request error when POSTing data and GETing response

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wcf, rest

I want to retrieve the details of the user (class) whose GUID matches in Database.
I'm using `WCF` `REST`ful web services in my `ASP.NET` `MVC` Project.

but, `WebResponse response =response .GetResponse()` giving Bad Request error 400 when POSTing the `GUID` and GETing `user` data in response.

Here's the `Interface`:

```
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke( Method="POST",
                    RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
                    ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
                    BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest,
                    UriTemplate = "Edit/{guid}"
                   )]
        User Edit(string guid);
```

Here's the `Controller Action`:

```
public ActionResult Edit(string guid)
        {
            if (guid != "0")
            {

                WebRequest Request = WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:65000/Service1.svc/Edit/guid");
                // Set the Method property of the request to POST.
                Request.Method = "POST";
                // Create POST data and convert it to a byte array.
                string postData = guid;
                byte[] byteArray = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
                // Set the ContentType property of the WebRequest.
                Request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
                // Set the ContentLength property of the WebRequest.
                Request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
                // Get the request stream.
                Stream dataStream = Request.GetRequestStream();
                // Write the data to the request stream.
                dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
                // Close the Stream object.
                dataStream.Close();
                // Get the response.
                WebResponse response = Request.GetResponse(); //THIS LINE GIVING BAD REQUEST ERROR 400

                // Get the stream containing content returned by the server.
                dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
                // Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
                // Read the content.
                string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();

                User UserData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User>(responseFromServer);
                ViewData["UserData"] = UserData;

                //  Clean up the streams.
                reader.Close();
                dataStream.Close();
                response.Close();

                return View(UserData);
            }

            return View(new User());
        }
```

P.S: below code is working fine which retrieves all the Users using `WebGet`.

I think the problem is only when I want to `POST` some data like guid and read `response`.

```
 public ActionResult Index()
        {
        WebRequest Request = WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:65000/Service1.svc/RetrieveAll");
        // Get the response.
        WebResponse Response = Request.GetResponse();
        // Get the stream containing content returned by the server.
        Stream DataStream = Response.GetResponseStream();
        // Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
        StreamReader Reader = new StreamReader(DataStream);
        // Read the content.
        string ResponseFromServer = Reader.ReadToEnd();
        // Display the content.
        List<User> UserData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<User>>(ResponseFromServer);
        ViewData["UserData"] = UserData;
        // Clean up the streams.
        Reader.Close();
        DataStream.Close();
        Response.Close();
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: Try by changing parameter from string to stream in the service. User Edit(string guid) -> User Edit(stream guid).

Also you don't need the uri template to contain {guid} for post

Comment: remove {guid} from your URI template and is your wbservice and MVC APP in the same domain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Author:

I've found that the problem was in dB connectivity while retrieving the data of User and the code mention in the question is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like url is not correct

WebRequest Request = WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:65000/Service1.svc/Edit**/guid**");

Should be(with guid in url)

WebRequest Request = WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:65000/Service1.svc/Edit/6F9619FF-8B86-D011-B42D-00CF4FC964FF");

Comment: and how to insert actual value of guid in URL

Comment: edit: ("http://localhost:65000/Service1.svc/Edit/guid"); passing the actual guid value, I can unit test it in edit(string guid) function body

Comment: DIdn't get your comment. "I can unit test it in edit(string guid) function body" - means you successfully reached method "User Edit(string guid);" and can debug it?

Comment: I mean edit() function is getting correct value of guid...nevermind problem was in dB connectivity...I've resolved it

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are not using the string guid as a variable but as a text, i think the correct url is this one:

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:65000/Service1.svc/Edit/" + guid);
```

If you use the word "guid" inside the "" it will be used as it is, a word, and not as the value inside the variable guid.
Hope it helped ;)